# What has to be done to delay the execution of next line in firefox browser while running robot scripts?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have used "Sleep" keyword in robot framework to pause the test executed for the given time. Expected time delay occurs in chrome and edge browser, But in Firefox the expected time delay doesn't occur. Instead error message is thrown as **ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine**

I have my script as follows:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element  ${drop_down_button}
Element Should Be Enabled  ${drop_down_button}
Click button  ${drop_down_button}
Element Should Be Visible  ${drop_down_item}
Click Element  ${drop_down_item}
Sleep  20s
```

In the above code, After clicking the drop down item, the test executed should pause for the given time. What has to be done to delay the execution of next line in firefox browser? How to handle this error **ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine**? To overcome this error I have tried Set "Set Selenium Implicit Wait", "Set Selenium Timeout" and "Set Browser Implicit Wait". But nothing worked.

Comment: In general Selenium devs recommend *not* mixing implicit and explicit waits - leaving the former to 0, as otherwise unexpected delays may appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share your environment details  - namely the version of the selenium library, Firefox and geckodriver.

There are reports this issue appears with selenium 3.12.0 and geckodriver 0.21.0, and is fixed with downgrade to geckodriver 0.20.1.

And it's fixed/not present with selenium 3.14.0 and geckodriver 0.21.0.

I'd suggest you get your environment in one of the two version sets, if it's not already there, preferably the later.

Comment: I have listed the version details below:

Comment: selenium - 3.12.0, ff - 57.0, geckodriver - 0.21.0

Comment: Which version of selenium and geckodriver should I install to overcome this issue

Comment: selenium - 3.14.0, geckodriver - 0.21.0; FF - latest public version (I think it's 60.something)

Comment: Thanks! it worked currently i have selenium 3.12.0 and downgraded my geckodriver to 0.20.1